# Proof for $ℝ^{n\perp}=0$, $0^{\perp}=ℝ^n$ and Orthogonal$\implies$ Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, independence

First, is it appropriate to just say the only vector that is orthogonal to every vector in $ℝ^{n}$ is the $0$ vector and do the same for reverse?

Second, is it true that orthogonal implies linearly independent but linearly independent does not necessarily imply orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the only vector orthogonal to all vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $0$-vector, but it looks like that is exactly the exercise.

You need to prove that if

$$x\cdot v = 0$$

for all vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $v=0$ (the $0$-vector).

You are also right that orthogonal implies linear independence, as long as all vectors are non-zero (but again this looks like something you need to prove), and certainly linear independence does not imply orthogonality.